# After upgrade to Jessie, crashes when external USB drive is connected

Tags: raspbian, usb, raspbian-jessie, crash, update

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 which was running successfully with Wheezy. I decided to upgrade to Jessie. When I plug in the external USB drive (LaCie Rugged THB USB 3.0), it crashes. I did an ssh and tailed the log while I plugged in the USB external drive and then it crashed:

```
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.094492] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.236915] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1075
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.236944] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.236961] usb 1-1.2: Product: Rugged THB USB 3.0
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.236976] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: LaCie
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.236991] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXF
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.238106] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar  3 19:53:38 raspberrypi kernel: [   90.242697] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Mar  3 19:53:39 raspberrypi kernel: [   91.235481] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LaCie    Rugged THB USB3  1153 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mar  3 19:53:39 raspberrypi kernel: [   91.238863] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Mar  3 19:53:39 raspberrypi kernel: [   91.254023] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Mar  3 19:53:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   92.244466] .
Mar  3 19:53:40 raspberrypi kernel: [   92.414881] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   92.671043] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.254476] .ready
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.254905] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.254931] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.255026] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.256447] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.256469] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Mar  3 19:53:41 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.256632] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   93.934461] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.076561] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1075
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.076581] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.076592] usb 1-1.2: Product: Rugged THB USB 3.0
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.076603] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: LaCie
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.076613] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXF
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.077411] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.077773] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.463130] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:43 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.719224] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   95.974460] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.116551] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1075
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.116575] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.116587] usb 1-1.2: Product: Rugged THB USB 3.0
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.116597] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: LaCie
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.116607] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXF
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.117732] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.118206] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Mar  3 19:53:44 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.511399] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   96.767492] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
Mar  3 19:53:46 raspberrypi kernel: [   98.024483] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:46 raspberrypi kernel: [   98.565110] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.074494] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.216825] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1075
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.216853] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.216870] usb 1-1.2: Product: Rugged THB USB 3.0
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.216885] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: LaCie
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.216900] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXF
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.217989] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar  3 19:53:48 raspberrypi kernel: [  100.218464] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Mar  3 19:53:49 raspberrypi kernel: [  101.120067] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:49 raspberrypi kernel: [  101.355329] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
Mar  3 19:53:50 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.634485] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.776880] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1075
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.776907] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.776924] usb 1-1.2: Product: Rugged THB USB 3.0
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.776939] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: LaCie
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.776954] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXF
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.778037] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  102.778517] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  103.168316] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:51 raspberrypi kernel: [  103.424463] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
Mar  3 19:53:53 raspberrypi kernel: [  104.684495] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:53 raspberrypi kernel: [  105.245152] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change
Mar  3 19:53:55 raspberrypi kernel: [  106.734484] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using dwc_otg
Mar  3 19:53:55 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Thu Mar  3 19:54:25 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Mar  3 19:53:55 raspberrypi kernel: [  106.876886] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1075
Mar  3 19:53:55 raspberrypi kernel: [  106.876916] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.5: Broken pipe
```

I have zero problems with this drive before on Wheezy. If I plug in this USB drive and plug the Raspberry Pi 2 in, it won't boot. I have tested this same drive on another Linux system and it worked perfectly.

Anything from the above log indicate what to do about this problem? Are there additional things for USB drives to install?

Comment: Have you tried using a powered usb hub for the drive? Also can you try using something such as a flash drive so that we can know that the USB ports on your Pi are not physically damaged?

Answer (score 1):

The lines:

```
Mar  3 19:53:42 raspberrypi kernel: [   94.463130] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change`
```

imply that somethings is wrong the the voltage that's being supplied to the drive. So there's a couple things that may be at work here.

**Upgrade Woes**:

The change from *Wheezy* to *Jessie* was drastic. So drastic that the foundation recommends not upgrading system in place, but rather doing a complete reinstall from a fresh image. There could be a number of systems that didn't handle the upgrade well, and are causing issues.

This might be fixable by going through different settings and doing a guess and check, but a reinstall would probably be easier/faster. It might be worth checking the max output settings in `config.txt`, but again, I'd suggest a clean install.

**Possible Hardware Issues**:

Either the drive or the port may have shorted. If it happens on the RPi, but works on the desktop, than the RPi may be damaged. If it doesn't work on the computer either, your drive is damaged.

The best way to check the RPi's ports would be to use a multimeter to check the power output of the USB ports.  If you don't have one, try a different drive. If it reacts similarly, you're back to the RPi have some kind of issue.

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. I did a clean install of Jessie. Was running Wheezy and decided to download Noob and start from scratch to select Jessie and take it from there.

Nothing else changed in the hardware environment. I don't see how all the sudden it is a power issue, unless this just happened to have occurred after installing Jessie.

What might I change in config.txt?

Comment: I think it might be easier, at least for trouble-shooting to put in a fresh install of Wheezy and see if the problem with the external USB drive goes away. Or do you believe the fresh install of Jessie somehow got messed up and I should try that again?

Comment: Interesting, I would check what the `max_current_usb` value is in `config.txt`. If it's not set, try  `max_current_usb=1`

Comment: There is no mention USB in the config.txt file. I've added max_current_usb=1, and rebooted. After it booted, I plug in the USB external drive and it crashed.

Comment: I went back to Wheezy, and still having a problem. It continues to be verbose in the logs and fdisk -l never recognizes the drive. It is making a clicking like sound, like it is trying to do something. However, it put it back on CentOS on a Dell server and it works fine and passed fsck.ext without a problem. Please advise me what specifically would I be looking for with using a multimeter on the USB ports? Thanks!

Comment: @Edward_178118: If you connect the multimeter to the RPi's USB [power pins](http://pinouts.ru/visual/USB.jpg), what's the output voltage?

Comment: I have the multimeter, but unfortunately the probes are too thick for me to get a reading to access pins 2 & 3. Could they be accessed from another part of the board? I appreciate your help.

Comment: A thought. It is possible this is being caused by a firmware upgrade? I did a clean install of Wheezy, but does that roll back the firmware too? This problem with the start of trying to go to Jessie, and I ran all the updates. Can firmware be rolled back?

Comment: with the tool "lsusb -v" you can see how much power/current is consumed per USB device/port.