# Connecting 4 WiFi USB Adapters to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, power, wireless-adapter

I'm trying to get 4 Wifi adapters running off the Pi (overkill I know), the adapter in question is the Alfa Network AWUS036NHA, the Pi runs smoothly and reads the adapters as I plug them in one by one until I plug the 4th one in and most/all of the USBs ports stop being read (sometimes few USBs are left working but it requires a reboot for them all to work again). 
[image]
I initially figured it to be a power issue (each unit seems to be 2W from what i've seen above) but when using an externally powered USB hub (https://www.robotshop.com/uk/7-port-usb-hub-raspberry-pi.html) I face the same issue... no matter what combination I use (ex. powering 2 adapters on the hub and 2 on the Pi). A second Pi 3 B+ that i have has been doing the same. Another solution I have tried is using 5V 5A supply and the only difference is that the 3 other adapters still stay on when the 4th is plugged in occasionally. Any possible ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `dmesg` say?

Comment: How are you powering the hub?

Comment: @GramThanos when run `dmesg | tail` and plug in the 4th adapter there doesn't seem to be a pattern, at least from what I can tell. This is what i get in a few instances (highlighted point where i plug the 4th) [album](https://imgur.com/a/p4JzwAX)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm powering it with a regular raspberry pi power supply (5V 2.5A), although I've tried with a 5A once and got the same issue

Comment: @BurgerGru This definitely seems like a power supply issue on the USB ports. Have you enabled USB over current on the pi (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43609/what-could-be-causing-over-current-change-all-the-sudden) and can you add a picture or describe how you are powering the USB hub. The hub you are using seems a little tricky to supply with properly. If you are using the microUSB connector on it, that is also limited to 2A of current and you probably need more than that. Also, where did you connect the 5A supply, directly to the Pi USB port?

Comment: @karan here is my [setup](https://imgur.com/8VODghs) i'm using the two 5V 2.5A plugs for both the pi and hub, there should be no power being transferred through the cable connecting the two (i've set the power link pins on the hub to not do so) so they're both being independently powered. The way i'm connecting the adapters is by putting 3 in the Pi and 1 in the hub so there should be enough power for the 4. [Here's one instance](https://imgur.com/1tok9j1) of me typing `lsusb -t` everytime I plug in an adapter. Also yes I had a micro-USB cut and supplied the 5A through there.

Comment: [Another instance](https://imgur.com/Uq3BLS6) I had plugged in the adapters in with the same method and was able to get a read on all of them in lsusb but when I tried to run `ifconfig` the terminal had hanged. Do you reckon that it could be a USB endpoint issue?